# Does rsync -L tag use target name or host name

Tags: linux, symlink, rsync, hardlink

I have a directory on a files on 2 different partitions, as i need these hardlinked rather than symlinked when they are rsync'd to my client server, does the -L option use the target name or the host name of the file ..

i.e. my symlink looks like:

file_a.txt_ahahagj -> /usr/local/etc/file_a.txt

does it use:
file_a.txt_ahahagj or file_a.txt

i need it to use file_a.txt_ahahagj if anyone knows how to do this it would be great

Comment: If the files are on different partitions, you are not going to be able to hard link them. Hard links work only within a single file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rsync -L does work for this scenario it will use the target name when syncing.